# complex javascript concatenation in timesheet.js

Tags: javascript, timesheet.js

I was just going through the code of **[timesheet.js](https://github.com/sbstjn/timesheet.js/blob/master/source/javascripts/timesheet.js#L35)** and came across the following piece of code:

```
var line = [
        '<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' + bubble.getWidth() + 'px;" class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default') + '" data-duration="' + (cur.end ? Math.round((cur.end-cur.start)/1000/60/60/24/39) : '') + '"></span>',
        '<span class="date">' + bubble.getDateLabel() + '</span> ',
        '<span class="label">' + cur.label + '</span>'
      ].join('');
```

I understand that a html element is being created here by the use of array syntax and the `join()` method, but i don't quite understand whats happening at this part of the code `Math.round((cur.end-cur.start)/1000/60/60/24/39)` what is happening here ? whats with the `/1000/60/60/24/39`  ??

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Looks like its converting ms to months (or 39 day units)

Comment: `cur.end-cur.start` gives time in milli seconds.. so `/1000/60/60/24` gives the time in days. I am not sure about 39

Comment: @JohnnyMopp 39 day units ? what does that mean ?

Comment: ask the developer on github, not here.

Comment: @Sachin yes the `39` part is kind of throwing me off the hook !

Comment: No idea. I assume it's relevant to timesheets?

Comment: Wow .... close vote for being `too broad` , you must be out of your mind !

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks ! i'll try making sense of it .. still does't make sense !

Comment: isn't 39 the number of weeks actually we work? (if you remove non working days)

Comment: @Saar That's possible: `(365 - (52 * 2)) / 7 = 37.3`

Comment: Thanks guys ! TY johnny , i guess thats the closest guess .

Answer (score -2):

It looks like it's taking a value in milliseconds, dividing by 1000 to get seconds, dividing that to minutes, hours, days...

Comment: what does it give dividing by 39?